# MySQL: Loop through one table and update another?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Table t1:

```
s (string)      |  x (int)
----------------+--------
"gfrdgeradfg"   |  0
"abdfodpnmn"    |  0
...             |  ...
```

Table t2:

```
c (varchar(1))
-----
"a"  
"c"  
"g"
"r"  
-----
```

I would like to add +1 to t1.x for every character t2.c that occurs in t1.s, i.e. the result should be something like this:

```
s               |  x
----------------+--------
"gfrdgeradfg"   |  3      (contains "a","g","r")
"abdfodpnmn"    |  1      (contains "a")
...             |  ...
```

Looping through t2 and update t1 in php is quite straightforward, but I'd rather do it in pure SQL, if possible.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE t1
SET x = (
    SELECT SUM(t1.s LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.c, '%'))
    FROM t2
)
```

Clarification: The expression `t1.s LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.c, '%')` will evaluate to a Boolean which is equivalent to `1` or `0` in MySQL.

*I didn't test it so please tell me if it doesn't work.*

Comment: Yours didn't work, ? because of bracket should be BEFORE SELECT--this seems to number crunch ok...(-still waiting for result, 60k lines...).
   UPDATE t1
   SET x = (SELECT
       SUM(t1.s LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.c, '%'))
       FROM t2
   )

Comment: I hope it's working OK, and it looks very neat. Although it's taking a very long time (t1 has 60k rows, t2 2k). -- If t1 was a very long table, but t2 had only very few (say 3) entries, would there be a speedier way of achieving this result by going primarily through the t2 entries??

Comment: Yes, it has worked very nicely (took about 10 mins). Thank you very much. (I suspect there might not be a much quicker solution...)